# How to make a similar text effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-identification, distort, text-wrap

Take a look on the attached text effect:
[image]

I've tried to make it with "Aachen Bold" font illustrator using : Envelope Distort -> Make with Wrap, but I can't get the result similar to the original one.

P.S: if the used font is not correct let me know.

Any suggestions! thanks in advance.

Comment: You're just trying to do the curved bottom or what effect on there are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm trying to make the curved bottom then make the lines effect inside the letters.

Comment: This image is a great example of how to express weight, mass and gravity with type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object > Envelope Distort` works here

[image]

If you then want the inner lines....

Set the fill to be white and the stroke to be black.

- Copy, Paste in front, `Object > Expand Appearance`
- Draw an ellipse to encompass the area of lines you *want* visible
- Set the fill of the *copy* to be a line pattern fill (`Swatch Panel > Open Swatch Library > Patterns > Basic Graphic Lines`)
- Select the line-filled copy and the ellipse and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

[image]

Then select the line-filled objects and via the**Appearance Panel** add an *additional* stroke set to white and aligned to the *inside*.

[image]

You can highlight the line pattern in the Appearance Panel and play with `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to alter the size of the lines themselves. Just tick the `Transform Patterns` option and UNtick the `Transform Objects` option in the Transform dialog window.

[image]

I don't believe you'll have any success trying to do all this one a single type object due to the pattern fill. It will require duplicating the object at least once.

Answer (score 1):

To make a live (editable) text version just make a custom pattern beforehand, sized accordingly...

Mine looked like this:

[image: Custom pattern fill for text]

Then I create my text, and make it white:

[image: White fill]

In the Appearance Panel add another fill, this time the  pattern:

[image: Pattern fill]

Then offset that fill to a negative value (Path > Offset Path):

[image: Offset pattern fill]

That's your effect all in one editable text layer; change the text/font as desired:

[image: Final result GIF]

You'll likely have to mess with the pattern independently using different typefaces; scale/move up/down, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For the shape you can use the Effect>Warp tools "Arc Lower" and "Arc".

For the bottom curve I applied -30% Bend in Arc Lower.

To get that small curve on the top I applied 4% Bend in Arc.

Metis' method for applying the fill lines is great.

[image]